# How does Boss-Loot in Elder scrolls online work?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

In other MMOs like WoW or SWTOR you usually have like 3-20 Items that can only be dropped by a certain boss. How does this work in ESO? Do the bosses of every instance have a Loottable aswell or do they just randomly drop some soulstones and a random green/blue Item?.

Also how are the dropchances? In WoW for example a Green/Blue+ drop is guaranteed if you kill a boss. In ESO I've killed a lot of bosses and I haven't got too many "good" Items from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm gonna give my answer based off of experience.

Each boss or dungeon (not sure) has unique items, how many unique items I couldn't tell you, that drop from bosses. They also drop the generic gear, for example "Leather belt of stamina". You are not always garunteed to get good items from a boss.

I have gotten everything from nothing from an entire dungeon to a couple epics in a dungeon, it is purely luck.

Also something to note, every elite boss in ESO has a unique item. Atleast that I have come across.